# arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer returns runtime error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, assertionerror

I am trying to update the style for a layer present in my saved map document with a source .lyr file present on my disk in the home folder. It returns an assertion error. The code I am trying to run is as follows:

```py
import os, csv, arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "\ArcGIS\Python_test"
PointFile = "\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_data.csv"
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management("Well_data_View, "Easting", "Northing", "Well_plot_EventLayer", "WGS 1984 UTM Zone 43N")
arcpy.Delete_management("Well_data_View")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("Well_plot_EventLayer", "\ArcGIS\Python_test", 'Well_plot')
arcpy.Delete_management("Well_plot_EventLayer")
mxd.saveACopy("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Python_workspace.mxd")
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Python_workspace.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
ul = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0]
sr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("\ArcGIS\Python_test\Well_SR.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, ul, sr, False)
```

'PointFile' is a CSV table on my disk which contains XY information being used to plot 'Well_plot_EventLayer' which in turn is converted to a shapefile 'Well_plot' which I do not export to my disk. After saving my map document, I store the map document path to variable 'mxd', the map layer to be update to variable 'ul' and the source layer (style template) 'Well_SR.lyr' to variable 'sr'. The error generated by the last line of code is:

```py
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1889, in UpdateLayer
    assert isinstance(source_layer, Layer)
AssertionError
```

Can someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Can you add a `print "{}".format(sr)` or `arcpy.AddMessage("{}".format(sr))` just before that last line?  This may give some idea of if that `sr = ...` line has worked as expected.

Comment: I think its your pathnames which you have starting with `"\ArcGIS\Python_test"` - are they on a local drive or on a shared drive?  Either way I think your paths need an `r` and more preceding them.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `arcpy.Delete_management("Well_plot_EventLayer")`?

Comment: The files, the path to which I have in my code are present on a local drive. Also, yes, there is more preceding the paths, I only kept the latter so as to not clutter the code in my post. @PolyGeo

Comment: `arcpy.Delete_management("Well_plot_EventLayer")` is to delete the XY event layer I have created in my code; it is just a temporary layer which exists only in the map document. I generate the shapefile 'Well_plot' from this event layer using `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()` after which there is no use of the event layer, hence I prefer to delete it to keep my ToC clean. @fatih_dur

Comment: `print "{}".format(sr)` gave the result `Well_SR` and `arcpy.AddMessage("{}".format(sr))` did not produce any message/result but still I guess the `sr = ...` line has worked...? @SonofaBeach